# jquery ajax call will not run the php script

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I am trying to do a simple name change for a user, which will save their new name into a db. For the ajax call, I am running something like this

```
var new_name = prompt("Enter your new name" , "Charlie Murphy");

  if(new_name == "" || new_name == null){
    alert("Please actually enter a name");
  }

  else{

    $.ajax({

       url : "./db_scripts/change_name.php",
       type : "POST",
       data : {name : new_name}


    });
```

My php goes

```
<?php


$new_name = $_POST['name'];
echo $new_name;

?>
```

Just to try and get the post to work, but the name is not printing to the browser. I am positive I have my path name right for the db_script, because I have other scripts that are working.

Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `success` handler to receive the data from your server page

```
$.ajax({
       url : "./db_scripts/change_name.php",
       type : "POST",
       data : {name : new_name},
       success: function(data){
         alert(data);
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried the success but was missing a comma after the data. This did it!